# jQuery function does not work on appended html form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following problems. I have 2 JQuery functions. One is for appending the content and the other one is for displaying the name of the selected file.

**FUNCTION 1**

```
<script> 
        jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ )
  {
   $("input[name=contribution_type]").on('change', function()
   {
    var value = this.value;

    $("#contribution").empty();

    if (value != 'none')
    {
        var div2 = 'content'
        $("#contribution").append(div2);
    }
   });

   });


       </script>
```

**FUNCTION 2**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(name){
        $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
            var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
            alert('The file "' + fileName +  '" has been selected.');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The **var div2 = 'content'** here is the whole form however it is too long so I did not include it.

Any ideas how on the second function for the file name will work in append()?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. You'll have to reattach that listener to the form. It's bound to the original page, but not the form elements which get appended by jQuery. So you'll have to wrap that into an eventListener() method & recall that method after the form is appended.

Comment: Good point Funk Forty Niner! The PHP tag has been removed. One could argue that the `<script>` tag is HTML, so the `html` tag could be valid. Most of it is JS, which appends HTML... but you were right about the PHP tag! It needed to be removed.

Comment: @Clomp Thank you, i will appreciate some help with the code :)

Comment: Read this section on [event propagation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/#event-propagation). It will allow you to attach event handlers to dynamically-created elements -- which I think is what you are asking. You would do something like `$(document).on('change', 'input[type="file"]', ...)` in your 2nd script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a working demo for you to look at & test out at [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/3xa92Lg6/).

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <input type="text" id="contribution_type" placeholder="Enter some text here..." />
    <div id="contribution">
        <button id="button1" disabled>Click me. This button will change into a form upload field.</button>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#contribution_type').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#button1').removeAttr('disabled');
});

$('#contribution_type').on('blur', function() {
    let value = this.value;

    $("#contribution").empty();
    if (value !== 'none') {
        let div2 = '<input type="file"><div id="contribution">Attach a file. Then press this button:<button>Test</button></div>';
        $('#contribution').append(div2);
    }

    $('input[type="file"]').on('blur',function(e){
        if (e && e.target && e.target.files && e.target.files[0] && e.target.files[0].name) {
            let fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
            let output = 'The file "' + fileName +  '" has been selected.';
            console.log(output);
            alert(output);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is how this works:

1. The `change` event doesn't work for `<input>` tags. It's for `<select>` elements. So it has to be switched to an event like: `blur`, `click`, `keyUp`, `keyDown`, `keyPress`, etc...
2. This attribute is obsolete: `type="text/javascript"`. We simply use `<script>` nowadays.
3. New [ES6](http://es6-features.org) updates allow us to use the [let](http://es6-features.org) keyword, which replaces the `var` keyword. It fixes problems with `this` and `that`, plus how they scope to JavaScript blocks... like `function () {...}` or `if (){...}` blocks.
4. The upload form needed some [object detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection), so that it wouldn't thrown an error when the form pops up. That's what the `e && e.target` line is all about.
5. The strict equality [type checking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Type_checking) operators, such as: `!==` and `===` are always preferred over loose equality operators, such as: `!=` and `==`. (The reason is that the JS code doesn't have to type cast to see if an integer 1 `==` a string '1'. That would be true, but `1 === '1'` would be false.)
6. You can replace `$(document).ready` with `$().ready`. See jQuery's API page on [.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for that short-cut.

I put in a `console.log` & an `alert()` method, so that you can see both examples. The `console.log` works better in loops than alerts. I wouldn't recommend 100+ looped alerts! ;-)

Hopefully, that'll point you in the right direction to get your upload form working. Good luck!